# Getting a result from a URL in C++

Tags: c++, url

I need a bare bones C++ version of some code.  Using Visual Studio 2017.

Friend of mine wants to get results from a URL link using c++.  He will write the .json parsers later, he then wants the code to visit the same URL domain and grab URL's that were in the same result.

I'm thinking it's got to be some sort of HTTP / HTTPS C++ GET requests maker function but I'm not sure.

looking for a possible template for this task, along with links to any necessary libraries for this project.

Answer (score 4):

libcurl (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is definitely a great HTTP/HTTPS client library which has all possible bells and whistles.

But there are others like:

- LibHTTP (https://www.libhttp.org/)
- CivetWeb (https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb)
- cpp-httplib (https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib)
- libwww (http://www.w3.org/Library/)
- LibHTP (https://github.com/OISF/libhtp)
- HTTP Parser (https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser)

There are already a lot of JSON parsers out there. To name a few:

- cJSON (https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON)
- ultrajson (https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson)
- JsonCpp (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)
- CAJUN (https://sourceforge.net/projects/cajun-jsonapi/)
- JSON for Modern C++ (https://github.com/nlohmann/json/)
- RapidJSON (https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson)
- tiny-json (https://github.com/rafagafe/tiny-json)
- json.h (https://github.com/sheredom/json.h)
- json-parser (https://github.com/udp/json-parser)
- libfastjson (https://github.com/rsyslog/libfastjson)
- liblaxjson (https://github.com/andrewrk/liblaxjson)

But there are more of them out there...

Up to you to make your pick based on which criteria are important to you (like: low footprint, performance, C++ API).